# Docker seems to ignore DOCKER_HOST and other vars set from `eval $(docker-machine env)`

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am on OS X, with docker installed through brew.  Trying to use the combination of docker-machine and docker.  Docker seems to ignore my environment settings.  How can I fix this?

```
   $ docker-machine env default2
   export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
   export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
   export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/kasterma/.docker/machine/machines/default2"
   export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default2"
   # Run this command to configure your shell:
   # eval $(docker-machine env default2)

   $ eval $(docker-machine env default2)
```

My understanding is that now everything is set up in the shell as it should be to use docker.  However:

```
   $ docker ps
   Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

If I specify everything on the command line it works

```
   $ docker -H tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 --tls --tlscacert /Users/kasterma/.docker/machine/machines/default2/ca.pem --tlscert /Users/kasterma/.docker/machine/machines/default2/cert.pem --tlskey /Users/kasterma/.docker/machine/machines/default2/key.pem ps
   CONTAINER ID        NAMES               IMAGE               STATUS
```

Together they seem to indicate the environment variables are ignored.  Note that they are set correctly (the more indented parts of the output here are, I believe, from the command line completion).

```
   $ set | grep DOCK
   DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/kasterma/.docker/machine/machines/default2
   DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
   DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default2
   DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
               if [ "${DOCKER_COMPLETION_SHOW_CONTAINER_IDS}" = yes ]; then
       case "$DOCKER_COMPLETION_SHOW_IMAGE_IDS" in
       if [ "${DOCKER_COMPLETION_SHOW_TAGS:-yes}" = "yes" ]; then
       case "$DOCKER_COMPLETION_SHOW_IMAGE_IDS" in
       if test ${DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME}; then
           if test ${DOCKER_MACHINE_PS1_SHOWSTATUS:-false} = true; then
               status=$(docker-machine status ${DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME});
           printf -- "${format}" "${DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME}${status}";
                   echo "Active machine: ${DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME}"
               if [ "${DOCKER_COMPLETION_SHOW_NETWORK_IDS}" = yes ]; then
       [ "${DOCKER_COMPLETION_SHOW_NODE_IDS}" = yes ] && fields='$1,$2';
       if [ "$DOCKER_COMPLETION_SHOW_PLUGIN_IDS" = yes ]; then
               if [ "$DOCKER_COMPLETION_SHOW_SECRET_IDS" = yes ]; then
       [ "${DOCKER_COMPLETION_SHOW_SERVICE_IDS}" = yes ] && fields='$1,$2';
       [ -z "$DOCKER_HIDE_LEGACY_COMMANDS" ] && commands+=(${legacy_commands[*]});
       if  ${DOCKER_MACHINE_WRAPPED} = true ; then
```

Here is my docker version information

```
$ docker -H tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 --tls --tlscacert /Users/kasterma/.docker/machine/machines/default2/ca.pem --tlscert /Users/kasterma/.docker/machine/machines/default2/cert.pem --tlskey /Users/kasterma/.docker/machine/machines/default2/key.pem version
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.8.1
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 21:43:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

And showing the docker binaries linking to the brew versions (with some stuff left over from having run the OS X version of docker before).

```
$ ls -l dock*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin       35 Jun  5 12:14 docker -> ../Cellar/docker/17.05.0/bin/docker
lrwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin       50 Jun  5 12:15 docker-compose -> ../Cellar/docker-compose/1.13.0/bin/docker-compose
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  4938393 Dec  4  2015 docker-compose.backup
lrwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma staff       91 Jun  5 11:54 docker-credential-osxkeychain -> '/Users/kasterma/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain'
lrwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin       50 Jun  5 12:12 docker-machine -> ../Cellar/docker-machine/0.11.0/bin/docker-machine
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  7417984 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-amazonec2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  8112752 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-azure
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  7355040 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-digitalocean
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  7343472 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-exoscale
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  7471952 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-generic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin 10575760 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-google
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  7362496 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-hyperv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  6830912 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-none
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  7709792 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-openstack
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  7778992 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-rackspace
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  7328400 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-softlayer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  8046416 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-virtualbox
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  7907168 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-vmwarefusion
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  7545600 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-vmwarevcloudair
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  7449392 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine-driver-vmwarevsphere
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  9039648 Dec  1  2015 docker-machine.backup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kasterma admin  9231840 Dec  4  2015 docker.backup
```

Comment: Do you have the same issue with the OS X version of Docker? You're running all these commands from the same terminal?

Comment: @BMitch Yes to both these questions; I switched to the brew docker to try and fix this.

Comment: Everything you're doing looks right to me. May want to try a `docker -D version` to see if there's more in the debugging output. For me, that output tends to be pretty minimal, so this is a shot in the dark.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Can you try this:
docker-machine env --shell <your shell> default2 and type the command that docker-machine prints in the end.

Comment: Nothing informative (`$ docker -D version
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.8.1
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`)

Comment: Also tried in a shell that is not in a tmux session, and in the default OS X terminal in place of iTerm2 (no idea what could be influencing this, so trying random stuff now).

Comment: Can you do a `which docker`, just to make sure that you are not triggering an alias or function?

Comment: I'm on Mac. This simple thing: `DOCKER_HOST='tcp://localhost:1234' docker ps`, print this: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:1234. Is the docker daemon running?`. Is it the same for you?

Comment: @Robert I get: $ DOCKER_HOST='tcp://localhost:1234' docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: @CFrei I get: $ which docker
`/usr/local/bin/docker`.  Note that this is the directory where I executed `$ ls -l dock*` as shown in the question.

Comment: It's too odd. If you can afford it, re-install docker

Comment: Is your shell redefining docker? `type docker`

Comment: @BMitch Make it an answer, and you get the bonus.  `$ type docker` 
gives `docker is aliased to `sudo docker'`.  The joy of an automatically synched bashrc; where the other machine is a linux machine.  It had been a while since I used this mac for docker stuff, and clearly completely forgot about this.  Problem solved!!! Thanks.

Comment: Interesting @CFrei mentioned alias, but `which docker` does not show this.  And just the mention didn't trigger me to check my bashrc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments, your `docker` command was aliased to `sudo docker`. The sudo command will not pass through the environment variables defined by docker-machine so it will default back to the /var/lib/docker.sock.

As for `which` vs `type`, `which` will point to a binary in the `$PATH` to let you know where something is located. `type` will let you know how the shell is running that command including shell built-ins, any aliases, or function definitions.

To solve this, remove the alias from your bash scripts and launch a new shell. In an existing shell that has the alias, you can run `unalias docker` or `/usr/local/bin/docker` (with the full path). In environments where you used sudo, consider adding the user to the docker group with:

`` sudo usermod -aG docker `whoami` && newgrp docker ``

That will give you group level access to the docker socket so you don't need to run sudo for the docker commands.